# Make a default Windows installation disk from a vendor disk?

Tags: windows-7, installation-media

I am wondering if it's possible to make a "clean" Windows 7 installation disk from a DVD that came with a new HP laptop, so that I can install a Dell laptop with a 64-bit version of the OS without having trouble with it's license?

The Dell (E6400) has a license for Windows 7 Professional and has 64-bit hardware, but I only have a 32-bit version of the OS when it was released.  We just bought an HP 5320m Laptop and I'd like to use the installation disk that came with the HP to install the Dell.  Obviously I don't want all the HP drivers and software and I want the licensing to be in order.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lifehacker recently highlighted a method to create your own [Custom Windows Install](http://lifehacker.com/#!5793427/how-to-create-a-custom-windows-installation-dvd-or-usb-install) using tools such as RT7Lite. There are links in the article for doing similar work with previous versions of Windows as well.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that (AFTER the weekend of course ;)).

Answer (score 0):

.You will not be able to use RT7 lite with HP restore discs, they are proprietary in nature, you are btter off downloading the version of W7 you need [from this page.](http://www.mydigitallife.info/download-windows-7-iso-official-32-bit-and-64-bit-direct-download-links/)